# Убрать последнюю запятую в строке PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть такая вот строка

$s = 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,

Как убрать последнюю запятую что бы было вот так

$s = 1,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: лучше обрати внимание на ответ teran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr($s, 0, -1);`
или
`preg_replace ('#\,$#', '', $s);`
или
`substr($s, 0, strripos($s, ','));`

Comment: На самом деле не совсем верный вариант, рабочий, но на мой взгляд лучше использовать rtrim, как предложил @teran.

Answer (score 5):

например так

```
$result = rtrim($s, ",")
```

а если вдруг, такая строка была получена с помощью кода вроде

```
foreach(range(1,8) as $num) $result .= "$num,";
```

то можно использовать

```
$result = implode(',', range(1,8));
```

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо, подправил.

Answer (score 1):

Хз насколько это правильно для php но точно работает =) и выше в ответах похожего подхода небыло:

```
$str[strlen($str)-1]=' ';
```

Это заменит последний символ строки на пробел(или можно ; ставить, при ручном формировании SQL запросов например =).

Comment: Кстати с версии 7.1.0 можно просто $str[-1] = ' ', то есть знак '-' укажет, что смещение с конца строки.

Comment: Спасиб за уточнение, только с 5ой версии на 7 перешел =) так будет удобней гораздо =)